# Get Selected Row On Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which does the following:

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter textWriter)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvNotifications.Rows)
        {
            if (gvRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                gvRow.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.previous_color=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFF99';this.style.cursor='hand';");
                gvRow.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=this.previous_color;");
                gvRow.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gvNotifications, "Select$" + gvRow.RowIndex,true);
            }
        }

        base.Render(textWriter);
    }

    protected void gvNotifications_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvNotifications.SelectedRowStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
    }
```

I have a button called btnTest and I would like to be able to cast the current row to my custom object. I have tried the following without any luck.

```
Customer currentRow = (Customer)gvNotifications.SelectedRow.DataItem;
```

'DataItem' is always null. I'm sure this is a easy fix but after Googling the problem I have yet to find anything that would work.

Here is my GridView in the aspx:

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="gvNotifications"
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    GridLines="None"
    CssClass="mGrid"
    AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#F0F0F0"
    AllowPaging="true"
    AllowSorting="true"
    PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
    PageSize="25"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvNotifications_PageIndexChanging"
    OnSorting="gvNotifications_Sorted" HeaderStyle-CssClass="srtAc" 
    onselectedindexchanged="gvNotifications_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Id" SortExpression="CustomerId" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="WhiteSmoke">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("CustomerId")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact Name" SortExpression="ContactName" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="WhiteSmoke">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("ContactName")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Use" onclick="btnTest_Click" />
```

Comment: What is this Customer ? is it any asp.net control ? you should be acces to any asp.net controles only in inside gridview control  .

Comment: Customer is the custom object I am trying to cast the row to.

Comment: did you get any error ?

Comment: No I don't get an error, but when I look at the new "currentRow" it's null. I am wanting to get the current selected row.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks John, sorry about that.

Comment: you must use a SqlDataSource and gridvie binded

Answer (score 0):

Try this for get selected row

```
protected void YourGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Grab the selected row
     GridViewRow row = YourGridViewId.SelectedRow;

}
```